# removing digit (numeric) from string php

Tags: php, regex

What is the easiest way to remove numbers from a string i have?
The strings look like this:

```
Green 1
Green 10
Green 100
Green 101
Green 102
Green 103
Green 104
Green 105
Green 106
Green 107
Green 108
Green 109
100 Bullets 1 
100 Bullets 10 
100 Bullets 11 
100 Bullets 12 
100 Bullets 13 
100 Bullets 2 
100 Bullets 3
```

I want them to look like this:

```
Green 
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
Green
100 Bullets
100 Bullets 
100 Bullets 
100 Bullets 
100 Bullets 
100 Bullets 
100 Bullets
```

My primary focus is removing the numbers from the strings. I think regular expressions would be good for this.

Comment: What if you try to solve it yourself first? That's the only way to learn

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: using explode method but it was not accurate

Comment: @Yaldram: what if you try doing that with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rexeg you can use is `\d+$`.

**Regex Explanation:**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

---

**Working code**

```
$rString = "12 foobar 123";
$nString = preg_replace("/\d+$/","",$rString);
echo $nString;
```

[See working example](http://ideone.com/6VgqrT)

---

**Note**

Because we only look at the end of the string we need to make sure that the end does not contains white-spaces. You can solve this with the `trim()` function in PHP.

```
$rString = trim("12 foorbar 123    ");
```

Comment: What about `100 Bullets 10 `? (also make a special note on the trailing space)

Comment: You're right, updated it.

Comment: I've intentionally put it there - "also make a special note on the **trailing space**"

Comment: not work !! i checked

Comment: @Yaldram: that's simple - instead of blindly copying code - have you tried to read and analyze it? You may not answer - we all know you have not.

Comment: @S.Visser: `$rString = "12 foobar 123 ";` <--- there is a **trailing space** in OP's example.

Comment: @zerkms just `trim()` it.

Comment: @S.Visser: I understand that, OP does not. So it makes sense to put it into answer

Comment: @zerkms Pretty basic stuff imho. But added it ;-) Ty for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think `preg_replace("#\s+\d+$#", "", $item);` should do the trick, but you have to parse the list line by line.

Comment: Character set is not required here.

Comment: well no need for list . i have my own method to achieve this.My main problem was how to code regular expression

Comment: @Yaldram: have you tried to solve your "main problem" yourself?

Comment: @zerkms yeah i solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `\d+$`. Make sure you trim your strings first